# Pointer not stoping at nested if statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

Debugged program by adding breakpoint and found pointer is not getting at nested if statement

afraid that nested if if else statement logic is correct.

```
- (void)bookmarkcurrentIndex {

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];

    if ([contentViewController.bookmarks containsIndex:currentIndex]) // Remove bookmark

        if (BookmarkState == NO) {

            [contentViewController.bookmarks removeIndex:currentIndex];

        }
        else {   

            [contentViewController.bookmarks addIndex:currentIndex];

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)bookmarkAction:(id)sender {



if (_BookmarkState != _bookmarkbtn.tag)
{
    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _bookmarkbtn.tag = 0;
     [self setBookmarkState:NO];

}
else
{
    [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];     
    _bookmarkbtn.tag = 1;
    [self setBookmarkState:YES];

}

_bookmarkbtn.tag = _BookmarkState;

[self bookmarkcurrentIndex];

}
```

Comment: Did you check the value of the parameters in each if statement?

Comment: stopping at the the first if statement and shows correct currentIndex value but not stopping at second if statement

Answer (score 1):

If `BookmarkState` is a `boolean` property, you're missing `self`. (Should be `self.BookmarkState == NO`.)

**Update:**

In your updated example code, you're comparing a `BOOL` to an `INT`. (`if (_BookmarkState != _bookmarkbtn.tag)`) which needs to be addressed.

You also need to update your if condition to use `_BookmarkState` or `self.BookmarkState`.

**Second update:**

You're currently checking if the `_BookmarkState != _bookmarkbtn.tag` but this is comparing a `BOOL` (YES/NO) to an `INT` (0/1). You should not do this. Instead, use the BOOL to determine state:

```
if (self.BookmarkState) { // If it's YES.
  [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-N.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else { // It's NO.
  [_bookmarkbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bookmark-Y.png"] 
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
self.BookmartState = !self.BookmarkState;
```

That's the first problem.

Comment: Edited—you're missing self.

Comment: gives parse issue on that after adding self

Comment: Can you please update your question with more code? If self.BookmarkState is giving a parsing error, there may be something larger that is an issue.

Comment: Is BookmarkState a boolean or an integer? You're comparing it to tags now.

Comment: yeah it is boolean. now that parse error is resolved but still not stopping at second if statement

Comment: Can you update your code? You're currently setting tags to booleans and comparing ints to booleans, which will never work.

Comment: i did updated to (self.BookmarkState == NO) but still not stopping at second if statement

Comment: updated if (_BookmarkState != _bookmarkbtn.tag) with if (self.BookmarkState) and removed  //_bookmarkbtn.tag = 0;
         //[self setBookmarkState:NO];  //_bookmarkbtn.tag = 1;
        //[self setBookmarkState:YES];
 but still not stopping at second if statement

Comment: Please update the code you've posted. It's completely unclear what your current code looks like.

Comment: there is not more code related to this issue basically uibutton added via storyboard when pressed it should toggle between bookmark and no bookmark which is working fine. next trying to set bookmark on current index and that is where i m having problem

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get individual state (i.e. is this one item bookmarked), which implies a model. But you're currently setting only one single BOOL for state, which doesn't make sense. I.e. right now you're saying BookmarkState YES or NO on the entire class, which would make it impossible to check the state on an individual item.

Answer (score 1):

When I match your opening and closing braces, they don't match up. Your outside if statement seems to be going nowhere. Take a careful look and see if I'm correct. Did you copy and paste your code directly into the form here? If so, something is wrong with your code. It should look like this:

```
- (void)bookmarkcurrentIndex {

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:contentViewController.page];

    if ([contentViewController.bookmarks containsIndex:currentIndex]) { // Remove bookmark

        if (BookmarkState == NO) {
            [contentViewController.bookmarks removeIndex:currentIndex];
        } 
        else {   
          [contentViewController.bookmarks addIndex:currentIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see that I reformatted it, and corrected it. You're missing the opening brace after `if ([contentViewController.bookmarks containsIndex:currentIndex])`. I hope this is your problem.

Comment: you are right. how can i miss that.fixed that part but still not stopping at second if statement